# Are dark skinned natives of Central America dark skinned due to the same genes as people of African heritage?

Tags: evolution, skin

I'm trying to understand how strong the evolutionary pressure on genes for skin color happens to be. Was it fast enough that the humans that migrated through the Bering Strait had lighter skin color and evolved darker skin color again afterwards?

Do the genes that give natives living near the equator in central America exist in African populations as well or are they new genes, that were likely evolved in that Central America?

Comment: The equator actually runs through South America, not Central America, so you might say tropical regions, rather than equatorial.  Also, you need to specify whether you mean the current inhabitants of the region, or the pre-Columbian ones.  I would suspect that there has been quite a bit of admixture of African (and European) genes in the current population.